# How to declare,initialize a integer variable and increment value of integer variable at each time when method is called again and again?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, variables, increment

Consider I want a integer variable called **page** and at first time its value will be 1.

See the sample code in sampleViewcontroller.m file,

```
// sampleViewcontroller.m 

        - (void)viewDidLoad {

        [self method1];
        }

        -(void) method1
        {

        // Here I am calling one API

        [self reload];

        }

        -(void)reload
        {

        // Here I want to use that page value, whenever this method is called, that value should be incremented by one.
       // and that page value I am passing as a parameter to another method, see below

         MyWebservices *webservices=[MyWebservices sharedInstance];

                [webservices getNextPageURL:_nextPageUrl pageValue:page callbackHandler:^(NSError *error,id json,NSString* msg) {

          // some code

             }

        }
```

in reload method I want use that page value, and want to pass below method as parameter,

```
[webservices getNextPageURL:_nextPageUrl pageValue:page callbackHandler:^(NSError *error,id json,NSString* msg)
```

and that method definition written in Webservices.m file, which is called each time when reload method is called. Here I want to take that page value every time, when it is increased and use that page to next api call.

```
// Webservices.m file

        -(void)getNextPageURL:(NSString*)url pageValue:(NSInteger)page callbackHandler:(callbackHandler)block{
            _userDefaults=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

            // I want to print this page value (which is incrementing every time)
            NSLog(@"Page value is : %@",page); // incremented value
            NSString *urll=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@&api_key=%@&ip=%@&token=%@&page=%@",url,API_KEY,IP,[_userDefaults objectForKey:@"token"],page];

            [self httpResponseGET:urll parameter:@"" callbackHandler:^(NSError *error,id json,NSString* msg) {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    block(error,json,msg);
                });

            }];

        }
```

so I want to pass **page** value from reload method to below method, so it will take incremented value at each time.

```
-(void)getNextPageURL:(NSString*)url pageValue:(NSInteger)page callbackHandler:(callbackHandler)block
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

write following in your .h file:

```
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger page;
```

now in .m file

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

 self.page = 1; // as you initially want page value to be 1. 
[self method1];  
}

-(void) method1
 {

 // Here I am calling one API
 self.page = page + 1; // as you want to increment the value of page when before function is called
 [self reload];
 }

 -(void)reload
    {

    // Here I want to use that page value, whenever this method is called, that value should be incremented by one.
   // and that page value I am passing as a parameter to another method, see below

     MyWebservices *webservices=[MyWebservices sharedInstance];

            [webservices getNextPageURL:_nextPageUrl pageValue:self.page callbackHandler:^(NSError *error,id json,NSString* msg) {

      // some code

         }

    }
```

Comment: Actually this is right because, I want to increment page value before above method is called each time              [webservices getNextPageURL:_nextPageUrl pageValue:self.page callbackHandler:^(NSError *error,id json,NSString* msg)

Answer (score 0):

Just hold a private property in your class, e.g.

```
@interface SampleViewcontroller() 

@property (nonatomic) NSInteger page;

@end 

@implementation

- (void)viewDidLoad {
  self.page = 0;
  [self method1];  
}

-(void) method1
{

  // Here I am calling one API

  [self reload];

}

-(void)reload
{

   // Here I want to use that page value, whenever this method is called, that value should be incremented by one.
   // and that page value I am passing as a parameter to another method, see below

   MyWebservices *webservices=[MyWebservices sharedInstance];    
  [webservices getNextPageURL:_nextPageUrl pageValue:self.page callbackHandler:^(NSError *error,id json,NSString* msg) {

      // some code
      if (!error) {
          //If success
          self.page++;
      }
  }

}        
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    You don't need to add a property, just add a private variable using anyone from the following ways:

    1. In .h file:

    @interface ViewController : UIViewController {

        NSInteger page;
    }

    OR 
    2. In .m file:


    @interface ViewController ()
    @end

    @implementation ViewController

    NSInteger page;

    // Now use the page variable in .m file:

    - (void)viewDidLoad {

        [self method1];
        }

        -(void) method1
        {

        // Here I am calling one API

        [self reload];

        }

        -(void)reload
        {

        // Here I want to use that page value, whenever this method is called, that value should be incremented by one.
       // and that page value I am passing as a parameter to another method, see below

         MyWebservices *webservices=[MyWebservices sharedInstance];

                [webservices getNextPageURL:_nextPageUrl pageValue:page callbackHandler:^(NSError *error,id json,NSString* msg) {

          // some code

             page ++;

             }

        }
```